# Postfix sends to original recipient name instead of alias name

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding, alias

I have setup Postfix as part of my ISPConfig implementation. It should just forward all mail. Clients should be able to define a new alias and receive mail on a different e-mail address, using ISPConfig.

Example: A mail sent to user1@domain1.com on my ISPConfig server should be forwarded to external mailbox user2@domain2.com
This works fine but one important thing.

When opening the mailbox for user2@domain2.com I see the mail with the original sender name, and the original recipient name, i.e. user1@domain1.com

I have tried the forward function and the send copy function on a mailbox in ISPConfig. Both cases show the original recipient user1@domain.com instead of the final recipient user2@domain2.com, as it would when I manually forward an e-mail.

Can this be achieved without having to maintain a list for each entry?

Comment: It sounds like you've described normal behavior for Internet e-mail.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Maybe you are right. But if I manually forward an email to you, your mail address with be shown as recipient, and not mine. It seems like the behavior I am seeing is more like redirecting instead of forwarding.

Comment: Indeed, this is normal auto-forwarding behavior.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You are new to email and apparently don't know the difference between the MAIL TO: envelope recipient and any To: headers in the message itself.

These are not the same; see RFC5321 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `enable_original_recipient = no` in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file. This disables the `Original-Recipient` headers being added to your outgoing email.

Source: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html